# Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I am working on google analytics (iOs, Objective c), when i add this file "libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a" to my project I got this error

```
"Apple Mach-O Linker Error"  "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".
```

I added below files successfully.

```
GAI.h
GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
GAIEcommerceProduct.h
GAIEcommerceProductAction.h
GAIEcommercePromotion.h
GAIFields.h
GAILogger.h
GAITrackedViewController.h
GAITracker.h

CoreData.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
```

When I add "libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a" this file i am getting error.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif?noredirect=1#comment96675821_43795385

Answer (score 2):

This problem has different solutions , one of them is to set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** . ( I don't know why by default it is **Yes** ) [image] This problem is a ghost like problem . Clearing Cache , Restarting Xcode , Simulator and MAC ,Ensuring proper linking of Frameworks or , Sometimes just doing nothing can solve this problem .